# Rails: How to keep at least one form section displayed in edit forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

Following [railscasts #196 Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments), I was able to implement a working add/remove function to my forms.

The problem is when I remove the last form section, submit, and edit form. The form section is empty and displays the "+ Add More" link only (since I removed the others when I submitted the form?).

By default, I used `@userprofile.programs.build` so the form builds one program section when it is first created.

userprofiles_controller.rb

```
def new
  @userprofile = Userprofile.new(params[:userprofile])
  @userprofile.programs.build
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<h3>Programs</h3>

<%= f.fields_for :programs do |builder| %> 
  <%= render 'program_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= link_to_add_fields "+ Add More", f, :programs %>
</div>
```

_program_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>  

  <%= f.select :program_name,  [['A'], ['B']], { label: "Program Name: ", :include_blank => "Please select a program...", { class: "form-control" } %>

  <%= f.select :program_role,  [['Student'], ['Teacher']], { label: "Program Role: ", :include_blank => "Please select your role..." }, { class: "form-control" } %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>

</fieldset>
```

Not sure how or if I need to add a condition and build in the userprofiles_controller.rb when the edit form is empty? So that if the whole section is removed, it still shows one form section by default and not just a empty section with the link to "+ Add More".

Or if there is some way so the first program section cannot be deleted. But the rest that are added has the "Delete" function?

Any insight would help, thank you!

**UPDATE**:

userprofiles.js.coffee

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .remove_fields', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your problem before I post an answer. So you want to hide the "Delete" link when there's only one field? Then when there are two or more fields, you want to show it, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a way to solve the problem I've been having. The problem is when I delete the program sections (all of the fields - since even the first program section has the "Delete" link) and submit the form. And when I go to edit the form, the program section would not show any fields, which I think saved from the submit.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll post an answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following HTML -- I added a couple of classes:

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="programs-form">
  <h3>Programs</h3>

  <div class="programs-fields">
    <%= f.fields_for :programs do |builder| %> 
      <%= render 'program_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= link_to_add_fields "+ Add More", f, :programs %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_program_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset class="program">  
  <%= f.select :program_name,  [['A'], ['B']], { label: "Program Name: ", :include_blank => "Please select a program...", { class: "form-control" } %>

  <%= f.select :program_role,  [['Student'], ['Teacher']], { label: "Program Role: ", :include_blank => "Please select your role..." }, { class: "form-control" } %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>

</fieldset>
```

Then, assuming you have jQuery loaded somewhere in your app, you can run the following script:

```
$(function () {
  $('a.remove_fields').hide();

  $('.programs-fields').on('change', function (ev) {
     if ($('fieldset.program').length > 1) {
       $('a.remove_fields').show();
     }
  });
});
```

I haven't had the chance to set up a test environment and run this code, so please let me know if you have any problems -- I'll be more than happy to fix any bugs!

Comment: I've added an edit to my question, and included `userprofiles.js.coffee`. I wasn't sure how to combine what I had with your jQuery. But I added your script separately to the file. One of the problems I noticed was that when I filled in more than one program section, saved and go back to edit. None of the filled in sections would have a "Delete" link. But when I edit one of the sections, the "Delete" link appears on all of the program sections - including the first one. I'm thinking its because of the `length > 1`. Is it possible to make sure the first form section never shows "Delete" link?

Comment: Or if everything is deleted, user update, goes back to edit form. To have edit build one program section by default if there was no program section saved from previous?